# Android Contact image set problem

Tags: android

I am trying to add contact. Adding name, phone etc are working. But adding contact image is not working. I don't get any exception. Here is my code.

```
Bitmap bmImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator +  "captured_receipt1.jpg");

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
bmImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, baos);    
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();

ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
          .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
          .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
          .build());

ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
.withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.DATA15,b) 
.build());
```

Comment: Use a try{ }catch(){} in there and add some test objects to separate out the some of the data for debugging...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to something similar to `.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)`.

Comment: I had solved this issue,  I forgot to mention the solution. Thanks IAmHappy, thank you very much.